# Viewport Centered <div> Alignment

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, viewport, viewport-units

I am trying to center content vertically in a viewport using `vh` units, and would like to have a second `<div>` aligned below and right, but still centered vertically in the viewport.

In other words, I'd like to have the `.reference` class aligned right and below the `.content` class, and both elements centered vertically in the viewport.

```css
body {
  background: rgb(0, 14, 32);
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.card { /* Should be vertically centered in viewport*/
  height: calc(100vh);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content { /* Should be horizontally left aligned or centered in viewport*/
  float: left;
  border: solid white;
  margin: 2 em;
}

.reference { /* Should be right aligned and below .content <div> in viewport*/
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  margin: 2 em;
  border: solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="content">
    Main Content
  </div>
  <div class="reference">
    Reference Content
  </div>
</div>
```

***Updated for final solution***

```css
body {
  background: rgb(0, 14, 32);
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.card { /* Should be vertically centered in viewport*/
  height: calc(100vh);
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;
}

.content { /* Should be left or center aligned in viewport*/
  text-align: left;
  border: solid white;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

.reference { /* Should be right aligned and below .content <div> in viewport*/
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  border: solid blue;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="content">
    Main Content
  </div>
  <div class="reference">
    Reference Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below
HTML:

```
 <div class="card">
      <div class="content">
        Main Content
      </div>
      <div class="reference">
        Reference Content
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: rgb(0, 14, 32);
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
   display: table;
   width:100%;
  text-align:center;

}

.card {
  height: calc(100vh);
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;


}

.content {
  text-align: left;   
  border: solid white;

}

.reference {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  border: solid blue;

}
```

Codepen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/qmVKjB

Comment: This is great!  I did notice that right content is cut off by the edge of the viewport.  Maybe a padding/margin issue?

Comment: yes @ZephyrMays, i just tried making it vertically center, if you apply padding or margin:2em as used ..that should work

Comment: Was just playing around with that - will work perfectly.  Much appreciate your answer!

Comment: Glad my answer helped for you :) ..Please let me know, if you stuck at any point

Comment: See update with your tweaks to OP.  I used the `rem` unit since using `em` units with different `font-size` elements could be inconsistent.

Comment: It is exactly what I was trying to accomplish.